# Horizontal scroll on menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Mobile device.

I've got the below list with buttons. I want them not to line-break but that the user has to scroll to the right.

I've tried `overflow-x:scroll, float:left` etc. but cannot get it to work.

[image]

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-2  ms-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist" style="overflow: scroll;">
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="btn btn-dark-blue active me-1" id="pills-company-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#company-tab"
               role="tab" aria-controls="pills-company" aria-selected="true">Företag</a>
          </li> <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="btn btn-dark-blue active me-1" id="pills-company-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#company-tab"
               role="tab" aria-controls="pills-company" aria-selected="true">Företag</a>
          </li> <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="btn btn-dark-blue active me-1" id="pills-company-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#company-tab"
               role="tab" aria-controls="pills-company" aria-selected="true">Företag</a>
          </li><li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="btn btn-dark-blue active me-1" id="pills-company-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#company-tab"
               role="tab" aria-controls="pills-company" aria-selected="true">Företag</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: That's because .nav has flex-wrap: wrap (bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by - however downside is that the inner .nav has to have a fixed width.

```
  .wrapper {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;

    .nav {
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
    }
  }
```